# Sending a POST request with mocked form-data in express

Tags: node.js, express, https

I have my express set up as a kind of proxy, whenever i hit /speise I want express to make a POST request to a certain website with form-data in its body. This is the request I want to perform in express:
[image: postman request]

I tried using axios and https.request to perform this but I know with neither of them how to parse form-data in the request body. 
This is the approach I tried using with axios:

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.viennafood.at/speise',
        headers: {
            'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=u1bdc2pgjuft7biqrbd9ea43c5',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
            'etlap_post': 'etlap_post',
            'week_31': '31. Woche',
            'body': JSON.stringify({'etlap_post': 'etlap_post', 'week_31': '31. Woche'})
        },
        data: {
            'etlap_post': 'etlap_post',
            'week_31': '31. Woche',
            'body': JSON.stringify({'etlap_post': 'etlap_post', 'week_31': '31. Woche'})
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(new Date(), 'Callback from request to viennafood');
        body = response.data;
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
        res.send(body);
        console.log(new Date(), 'Sent response to client');
        next();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

And this is the approach with https.request:

```
var options = {
        hostname: HTTPS_HOST,
        port: HTTPS_POST,
        path: API_ENDPOINT,
        method: HTTP_METHOD,
        headers: {
            'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=u1bdc2pgjuft7biqrbd9ea43c5',
            'etlap_post': 'etlap_post',
            'week_31': '31. Woche',
            'body': JSON.stringify({'etlap_post': 'etlap_post', 'week_31': '31. Woche'})
        }
    }, body = '';

    console.log(new Date(), 'Sending request to viennafood');

    var requ = https.request(options, function(https_res) {
        console.log(new Date(), 'Callback from request to viennafood');

        /*
        * For future use, if the cookie gets invalid 
        */
        if (https_res.headers['set-cookie']) {
          let sessionId = https_res.headers['set-cookie'].toString().split('=')[1].split(';')[0];
        }

        https_res.on('data', function(d) {
          body += d;
        });

        https_res.on('end', function() {
            res.send(body);
            console.log(new Date(), 'Sent response to client');
            next();
        });
    });
    requ.end();
```

Neither of them perform the same request as postman, I hope someone of you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to serialize the request payload using [querystring.stringify](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) as suggested in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#nodejs):

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://www.viennafood.at/speise',
  headers: {
    'Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=u1bdc2pgjuft7biqrbd9ea43c5',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    'etlap_post': 'etlap_post',
    'week_31': '31. Woche',
    'body': JSON.stringify({'etlap_post': 'etlap_post', 'week_31': '31. Woche'})
  },
  data: querystring.stringify({
    'etlap_post': 'etlap_post',
    'week_31': '31. Woche',
    'body': JSON.stringify({'etlap_post': 'etlap_post', 'week_31': '31. Woche'})
  })
});
```